# Error messages are getting printed in all the log files

Tags: log4j2

The log error messages are getting printed to all the log files instead of the error file. Not sure what i have missed in the configuration. Can anyone check and let me know

I tried all permutations and combinations but nothing seems to be working.
I think i am missing some configuration but not sure what it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%X{id}] ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>


     <Appenders>
         <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="ROOTLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}- [%-5level] : %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />

            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
             <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ERRORLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
             <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.org.bot" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ERRORLOGS" />
            <appender-ref ref="ROOTLOGS" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ROOTLOGS"  />
            <AppenderRef ref="ERRORLOGS" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Expectation is that error messages should only get printed to boterror.log file and normal application messages should get printed to bot.log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what finally did the trick. Whatever **sazzad** has suggested + i need to add threshold filter to ERRORLOG without which normal logs were also getting added to it.

This is the final configuration which is working as per my expectations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%X{id}] ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>


     <Appenders>
         <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="ROOTLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}- [%-5level] : %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />

            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />

             <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ERRORLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
           <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/> 
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.org.bot" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ERRORLOGS" />
            <appender-ref ref="ROOTLOGS" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ROOTLOGS"  />
            <AppenderRef ref="ERRORLOGS" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

*DENY* error messages from `ROOTLOGS`.

```xml
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="ROOTLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}bot-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}- [%-5level] : %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ERRORLOGS" fileName="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:LOG_DIR}boterror-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
```